# C - Pass struct by reference

Tags: c, struct, pass-by-reference

I am trying to pass a structure by reference in C so that I can modify the values from within the function. This is the code I have so far, but it produces some warnings and one error.

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myfunctions.h"
#include "structures.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[] {

    struct MyStruct data;

    data.value = 6;

    printf("Before change: %d\n", data.value);

    changeData(data);

    printf("After change: %d\n", data.value);

}
```

myfunctions.c

```
#include "structures.h"

void changeData(MyStruct data) {
    data.value = 7;
}
```

myfunctions.h

```
#ifndef MyStruct
#define MyStruct

void changeData(MyStruct data);

#endif
```

structures.h

```
typedef struct {

    int value;

} MyStruct;
```

Errors Produced

```
In file included from main.c:2:0:
myfunctions.h:4:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
 void changeData(MyStruct data);
 ^
In file included from main.c:3:0:
structures.h:5:1: warning: unnamed struct/union that defines no instances
 } MyStruct;
 ^
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:9:5: error: ‘data’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     data.value = 6;
     ^
main.c:9:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

Comment: `void changeData( MyStruct *data)` , and `changeData(&data)`

Comment: If you want to pass a pointer to the structure, you need to do that explicitly.

Comment: Make sure you check **Related** on the right side of the page. Your title appears many times.

Comment: just an fyi... there is no pass by reference in C. C is entirely pass by value. When you pass a pointer into a function, a local copy is made in that function, and dereferencing it points to the same memory address as the pointer in the caller.

Comment: to start, this line: `int main(int argc, char const *argv[] {` is missing the closing paren `)` before the opening brace '{'

Comment: when not using the parameter of the `main()` function, to avoid the warnings from the compiler about unused parameters, us the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: in the main() function, this line: `struct MyStruct data;` is not correct.  Because `MyStruct` is a typedef of a struct, so must not have the `struct` modifier

Comment: in main(), this line: `changeData(data);`  cannot change the data in main()  suggest changing to `changeData(&data);`  <-- notice the address of 'data' is being passed.  then the signature of changeData() should be `void changeData(MyStruct *data)`  so it is expecting a pointer,  Then the body of changeData should be: `data->value = 7;`

Comment: in general, the name used in the 'include guard' of a header file should reflect the name of the file, not some item in the contents.

Answer (score 6):

That's all caused by

```
#define MyStruct
```

With this line, you've defined `MyStruct` as a macro that expands to nothing. I.e. you've effectively removed all occurrences of `MyStruct` in the following code, which is why the compiler is so confused about seeing things like

```
typedef struct {

    int value;

} ;
```

or

```
void changeData( data);
```

---

To fix this, use

```
#ifndef MYFUNCTIONS_H_
#define MYFUNCTIONS_H_
```

instead. (This is the reason why we use `ALL_UPPERCASE` names for macros: To avoid accidental name clashes with normal identifiers.)

Answer (score 0):

applying all my comments and elimination of the unnecessary 'typedef', and placing it all in one file ( Note: there is no problem with extracting the various files), results in the following code:

```
#ifndef STRUCTURES_H
#define STRUCTURES_H

struct MyStruct
{
    int value;
};
#endif // STRUCTURES_H



#ifndef MYFUNCTIONS_H
#define MYFUNCTIONS_H

void changeData( struct MyStruct *data);

#endif // MYFUNCTIONS_H





#include <stdio.h>
//#include "myfunctions.h"
//#include "structures.h"

int main( void )
{
    struct MyStruct data;

    data.value = 6;

    printf("Before change: %d\n", data.value);

    changeData(&data);

    printf("After change: %d\n", data.value);
} // end function: main



//#include "structures.h"

void changeData( struct MyStruct *data)
{
    data->value = 7;
} // end function: changeData
```

which cleanly compiles and does do the desired operation